# ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest not calling ScheduledTaskAgent's OnInvoke after initial install

Tags: windows-phone-7, scheduled-tasks, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Let me start by saying that I had the PeriodicTask already working a couple of days back, but when I came back to do something else I noticed the PeriodicTask's OnInvoke is not called anymore.

I think I am doing the basics correct: removing existing PeriodTask if found, calling LaunchForTest only in debug build and I've checked that the ScheduledAgent is referenced properly in the project and the WMAppManifest.xml.

This is how I setup the PeriodicTask:

```cs
            try
            {
                PeriodicTask backgroundTask = null;
                backgroundTask = ScheduledActionService.Find(BGTASK_NEW_EPISODES) as PeriodicTask;
                if (backgroundTask != null)
                {
                    ScheduledActionService.Remove(backgroundTask.Name);
                }

                // Start our background agent.
                backgroundTask = new PeriodicTask(BGTASK_NEW_EPISODES);
                backgroundTask.Description = "Foobar";

                ScheduledActionService.Add(backgroundTask);
#if DEBUG
                ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(BGTASK_NEW_EPISODES, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
#endif
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException e)
            {
                if (e.Message.Contains("BNS Error: The action is disabled"))
                {
                    App.showNotificationToast("Background tasks have been disabled from\nsystem settings.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) {  }
       }
```

Here's my WMAppManifest.xml:

```
  <ExtendedTask Name="BackgroundTask">
    <BackgroundServiceAgent Specifier="ScheduledTaskAgent" Name="PodcatcherBackgroundService" Source="PodcatcherBackgroundService" Type="PodcatcherBackgroundService.ScheduledAgent" /> 
  </ExtendedTask>
```

When I install the app for the first time, then the OnInvoke is called. But if I restart the app, it's not called. The same is true for both device and emulator.

I've also verified that the background task is enabled in settings and I have a fully charged battery (device is a WP7 device and it's connected via USB to PC. For the emulator, of course, this doesn't matter).

So what should I check next?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, seems I got it resolved.

In certain cases I forgot to call `NotifyComplete()` in the background task. In that case Windows Phone seems to just ignore subsequent tries to invoke the background worker.

Comment: Further to this, the process itself (HeadlessHost.exe) doesn't exit until you call `NotifyComplete` (or `Abort`), and a new copy of the task won't start until the old one exits.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I must add one more question for debugging; do you know what's the best way of "cleaning" the state when debugging background tasks if I suspect something is wrong? Is reinstalling the app enough, or is then something kept hanging?

Comment: Uninstalling the app definitely terminates any running processes, as well as clearing the isolated storage.

Comment: I encountered this issue and uninstalling the app was not enough - it only worked after I uninstalled the app then restarted the phone.